# Ошибка заполнения массива при парсинге JsonObject

Tags: android, массивы, json, android-asynctask

Добрый день. Допускаю детскую ошибку, но не могу найти решение. Подскажите где нужно исправить. Есть класс, который наследуется от **AsyncTask< Void, Void, String>**. Здесь объявляю массив:   **public  String myArray[];**
В методе **doInBackground** происходит получение Json файла и он возвращается в **resultJson**. В методе **onPostExecute** достаю строки из Json файла и в цикле заполняю ими массив:

```
    public class CategoryTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    JSONObject dataJsonObj;
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
    public  String adress =     
    String resultJson = "";
    public  String myArray[];

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        BufferedReader reader;
        try {

                URL url = new URL(adress);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                resultJson = buffer.toString();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
         }

        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
        finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return resultJson;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(strJson);
            JSONObject object;

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    myArray[i] = object.getString("PARAMETER");             
            }


        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();        }        }
}
```

Получаю такую ошибку:

> 03-23 19:42:14.776 7568-7568/com.MyApp D/AndroidRuntime:
>   Shutting down VM 03-23 19:42:14.776 7568-7568/com.MyApp
>   W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0xa61f3908) 03-23 19:42:14.776 7568-7568/com.MyApp
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                           at
>   com.MyApp.AsyncTasks.CategoryTask.onPostExecute(CategoryTask.java:122)
>                                                                           at
>   com.MyApp.AsyncTasks.CategoryTask.onPostExecute(CategoryTask.java:22)
>                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
>                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>                                                                           at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

122 строчка: **myArray[i] = object.getString("PARAMETER");**

22 строка: **public class CategoryTask extends AsyncTask {**

Comment: а если вывести сам jsonArray. там точно adress или address?

Comment: @MrGarison в переменных очепяток нет) если в цикле, вместо заполнения массива, выводить каждый элемент jsonArray, то все показываются...

Comment: сам массив `myArray` создается где-нибудь?

Comment: Плохо оформленный код в вопросе (выглядит странно). Инициализация myArray не показана, примера json строки нет. Гадать можно долго...

Comment: @ШуткоАлександр я добавил весь код

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Массив у вас просто объявлен, но не проинициализирован. Т.е. `myArray == null`. Именно поэтому и ошибка. Массив можно проинициализировать вот так: `myArray = new String[100500]` (где 100500 - количество записей в массиве), либо если количество записей заранее неизвестно использовать ArrayList:

```
List<String> myArray = new ArrayList<>();
myArray.add("String1");
myArray.add("String2");
myArray.add("String3");
myArray.get(0);
myArray.get(1);
```